# Solidity: Transaction that requires multiple people to approve before being sent?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, payment, smartcontracts, escrow

How can I go about creating a function that can do this?

Example:
Person 1 created the transaction and sets an amount.
Person 2 approves the transaction and the amount gets sent to the contract till approved by Person 1.
Person 1 approves and the amount gets sent to Person 1 (or another address) from the contract (or Person 2).

I tried multiple escrow tutorials but couldn't get them to work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to create is called a multisignature wallet.

The most well-known multisignature wallet for Ethereum and [EVM-compatible blockchains](https://tradingstrategy.ai/glossary/evm-compatible) is Gnosis Safe.

You can study [Gnosis Safe source code to understand how to build your own multisignature wallet](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/Safe.sol).

For simpler examples, you can look up old [Parity multisignature wallet](https://github.com/parity-contracts/0x863df6bfa4/blob/master/contracts/walletLibrary.sol) which had one of its versions hacked many years ago.